# GET method without loading URL

Tags: ajax, api, get

This is more of a theoretical question but I'd like to know what is going on.
I've created a site using `angularjs` where I load data from an external file.

When I open up Firefox developer(F12) tool I get to see a GET request as expected.
Something like this(the screenshot is taken from https://www.ted.com/talks/daniel_kish_how_i_use_sonar_to_navigate_the_world)
[image]

Now, when I load https://www.ted.com/ I get an empty load but I'm sure the page uses API with a GET method to get the list of data and output the list of videos.
[image]

So what exactly is going on here? How come I don't get to see the GET requests URLs loaded inside the console?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like going to any TED.com/..... URL results in TED.com loading a whole bunch of stuff not only necessary for whatever specific url you are headed to requires, but also that the developers predict you might need in the future (such as the video metadata for the homepage).

You could implement this yourself in AngularJS with a service that gets a bunch of data initially on load and caches it for future use if needed.

Another possibility is that FireFox itself caches a lot of the GET request replies it receives and keeps them around for future calls so that your pages load faster on average.

Comment: ok, what about this site https://bluehill.overdrive.com/. Where are all the GET urls?